# Understanding GridBagConstraints gridx and gridy

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am trying to use the gridx and gridy constraints to create an interface as shown below(ignore the Next button). The first two JLabel-JTextField pair works fine but I am not sure what gridx and gridy values do I set for the remaining 10 fields.

[image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class InitialPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3159520372145273536L;

    /**
     * @param gridBagLayout
     */
    public InitialPanel() {

        super();

        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * For each component to be added to this container:
     * 
     * 1. Create the component 
     * 2. Set instance variables in the GridBagConstraints instance
     * 3. Add component to panel.
     * 
     */
    private void initComponents() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        // All mandatory fields.

        // 1.

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;

        JLabel hwCodeLabel = new JLabel("HW CODE:");

        this.add(hwCodeLabel, gridBagConstraints);


        JTextField hwCodeTextField = new JTextField("");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;

        hwCodeTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(hwCodeTextField, gridBagConstraints);


        // 2.

        JLabel publisherIdLabel = new JLabel("PUBLISHER ID:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(publisherIdLabel, gridBagConstraints);



        JTextField publisherIdTextField = new JTextField("");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        publisherIdTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(publisherIdTextField,gridBagConstraints);



        /*// 3.
        JLabel journalTitleLabel = new JLabel("JOURNAL TITLE:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        this.add(journalTitleLabel,gridBagConstraints);




        JTextField journalTitleTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(journalTitleTextField,gridBagConstraints);


        // 4.


        JLabel printISSNLabel = new JLabel("PRINT ISSN:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 3;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(printISSNLabel,gridBagConstraints);



        JTextField printISSNTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 3;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(printISSNTextField,gridBagConstraints);


        // 5.

        JLabel eISSNLabel = new JLabel("ELECTRONIC ISSN:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 4;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(eISSNLabel,gridBagConstraints);


        JTextField eISSNTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 4;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(eISSNTextField,gridBagConstraints);


        // 6.

        JLabel publisherNameLabel = new JLabel("PUBLISHER NAME:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 5;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(publisherNameLabel,gridBagConstraints);



        JTextField publisherNameTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 5;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(publisherNameTextField,gridBagConstraints);



        // 7.

        JLabel publisherLOCLabel = new JLabel("PUBLISHER LOCATION:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 6;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(publisherLOCLabel,gridBagConstraints);



        JTextField publisherLOCTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 6;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(publisherLOCTextField,gridBagConstraints);



        // 8.

        JLabel coverDateLabel = new JLabel("COVER DATE:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 7;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(coverDateLabel,gridBagConstraints);


        JTextField coverDateTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 7;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(coverDateTextField,gridBagConstraints);


        // 9.

        JLabel volumeLabel = new JLabel("VOLUME:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 8;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(volumeLabel,gridBagConstraints);



        JTextField volumeTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 8;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(volumeTextField,gridBagConstraints);


        // 10.

        JLabel issueLabel = new JLabel("ISSUE:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 9;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(issueLabel,gridBagConstraints);



        JTextField issueTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 9;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(issueTextField,gridBagConstraints);


        // 11.

        JLabel copyrightStatementLabel = new JLabel("COPYRIGHT STATEMENT:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 10;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(copyrightStatementLabel,gridBagConstraints);



        JTextField copyrightStatementTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 10;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(copyrightStatementTextField,gridBagConstraints);


        // 12.

        JLabel copyRightYearLabel = new JLabel("COPYRIGHT YEAR:");

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 11;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;

        this.add(copyRightYearLabel,gridBagConstraints);


        JTextField copyRightYearTextField = new JTextField();

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 11;

        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

        journalTitleTextField.setColumns(10);

        this.add(copyRightYearTextField,gridBagConstraints);
*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I modified your program to get the desired result, I also have added two methods to make your code more readable and efficient :

```
public class InitialPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3159520372145273536L;

    public InitialPanel() {
        super();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        // All mandatory fields.
        // 1.
        JLabel hwCodeLabel = addMyLabelCell(0, "HW CODE:");
        JTextField hwCodeTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(0, "");

        // 2.
        JLabel publisherIdLabel = addMyLabelCell(1, "PUBLISHER ID:");
        JTextField publisherIdTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(1, "");

        // 3.
        JLabel journalTitleLabel = addMyLabelCell(2, "JOURNAL TITLE:");
        JTextField journalTitleTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(2, "");

        // 4.
        JLabel printISSNLabel = addMyLabelCell(3, "PRINT ISSN:");
        JTextField printISSNTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(3, "");

        // 5.
        JLabel eISSNLabel = addMyLabelCell(4, "ELECTRONIC ISSN:");
        JTextField eISSNTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(4, "");

        // 6.
        JLabel publisherNameLabel = addMyLabelCell(5, "PUBLISHER NAME:");
        JTextField publisherNameTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(5, "");

        // 7.
        JLabel publisherLOCLabel = addMyLabelCell(6, "PUBLISHER LOCATION:");
        JTextField publisherLOCTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(6, "");

        // 8.
        JLabel coverDateLabel = addMyLabelCell(7, "COVER DATE:");
        JTextField coverDateTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(7, "");

        // 9.
        JLabel volumeLabel = addMyLabelCell(8, "VOLUME:");
        JTextField volumeTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(8, "");

        // 10.
        JLabel issueLabel = addMyLabelCell(9, "ISSUE:");
        JTextField issueTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(9, "");

        // 11.
        JLabel copyrightStatementLabel = addMyLabelCell(10, "COPYRIGHT STATEMENT:");
        JTextField copyrightStatementTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(10, "");

        // 12.
        JLabel copyRightYearLabel = addMyLabelCell(11, "COPYRIGHT YEAR:");
        JTextField copyRightYearTextField = addMyTextFieldCell(11, "");
    }

    public JLabel addMyLabelCell(int pos, String labelstr) {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = pos;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(labelstr);
        this.add(label, gridBagConstraints);
        return label;
    }

    public JTextField addMyTextFieldCell(int pos, String text) {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 10;
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(text);
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = pos;
        textField.setColumns(10);
        this.add(textField, gridBagConstraints);
        return textField;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(new InitialPanel());
            f.setSize(300, 300);
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

[image]

Comment: You can add the spacing between rows if you want (as shown in image you provide) with the help of `inset` constraint : `gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 8, 0);`

Comment: Thanks, but why does my [code](http://pastebin.com/4if42bza) not works as expected - where am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Sandeep Why you have placed so many unnecessary `new lines` in your code.

Comment: @Sandeep reply. I know why yours wasn't working. but your indentation made me so difficult to understand your code. You have made your code so lengthy.

Comment: @Sandeep add this `gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;` just after when you have created your `gridBagConstraints`. I recommend you to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

For all rows, gridy should be the row number, and gridx will be 0 for the label and 1 for the textfield.

Correct your code and verify that this solves your problem

Comment: also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#gridx

Comment: His may be a little tricky since he has that button in the left upper corner to throw things off. He may need to combine the button and the label on a JPanel.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels poster advised to ignore the button

Comment: @ControlAltDel It still doesn't work as expected. Here is the [modified code(as per your suggestion)](http://pastebin.com/4if42bza) and the [output](http://i.imgur.com/rkZM4Le.png).

Comment: @Sandeep seems like your JTextFields are too small? You might try JTextField.setColumns(10) and/or set GridBagConstraints.fill to HORIZONTAL or BOTH